# How can I simplify my if-else statement in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

In my code I have a method `size(MyData)` that returns size of data - it can be 0 or greater.
I also have a flag `exclude` that can be `true` or `false`. The point of my algorithm is to do some operation on data based on its size and the value of the flag.

- If the size is greater than 0, I want to do operation on data.
- If the size is 0, then I need to check the value of the flag `excluded`. In that case, if the flag `excluded` is set to true, I don't want to do operation on data. But if the flag is set to false, I need to do operation on data.

This is my algorithm so far:

```
int numberOfKids = size(MyData); //this can be 0 or greater
if (numberOfKids != 0) {
    //do operation
}
else {
    if (!exclude) {
        //do operation
    }
}
```

is there a better way of writing this algorithm? 
Thanks!

Comment: `if (numberOfKids != 0) { // do stuff } else if (!exclude) { // do stuff }`

Comment: You mean `if (numberOfKids!=0 || !exclude) { do operation }` ?

Comment: if the operations are the same then the `||` (OR) method is even cleaner

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Java if statement tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it's the same operation:

```
int numberOfKids = size(MyData); //this can be 0 or greater
if (numberOfKids != 0 || !exclude) {
    //do operation
}
```

The `||` comparison works by evaluating the left side, and if it is true, the right side is skipped. But if the left side is false, then the right side is evaluated.